# My method from another class is not being called?

Tags: java, image, class, object, methods

Alright I am super confused right now, I am using a piece of code in my program that is 95% similar to another piece I've used in an another program, the only difference is that it worked in the previous program...

it is basically a Image loading class/method and I'm trying to call it in my main class but its not working and the "cannot find symbol - class Image" error occurs.

Where I'm calling the method from my GameImage class:

```
    //STORE IMAGES
private static Image background;
```

GameImage class:

```
public class GameImage
{
public static Image loadImage(String imagePathName) {

    // All images are loades as "icons"
    ImageIcon i = null;

    // Try to load the image
    File f = new File(imagePathName);


    if(f.exists()) {  // Success. Assign the image to the "icon"
        i = new ImageIcon(imagePathName);
    }
    else {           // Oops! Something is wrong.
        System.out.println("\nCould not find this image: "+imagePathName+"\nAre file name and/or path to the file correct?");            
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // Done. Either return the image or "null"
    return i.getImage();

} // End of loadImages method

}
```

Where I load the image in main class:

```
        //load the images
    background = GameImage.loadImage("Images//background.jpg");
```

So yeah I dont know why that error keeps popping up because ive used that exact same code structure and GameImage class in another program... hmm

Any help would be great thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lack the `Image` import statement.

Import the `Image` class and you should be fine.

Comment: My imports are:

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;

Similar to my other program so Im not too sure it would be an import issue?

Comment: Never mind you were right I forgot to import java.awt.*
Thanks :)